# Android draw directly onto a bitmap in a non-ui class (no canvas)

Tags: android, android-image

I'm working with some data I've captured with an external sensor and I have it as a bitmap. I want to draw some annotations over it and then save it to a file. Is there a native Android way to do this?  Like some standard 2D graphic calls?  I just want to draw text and some lines. All the examples I have found use canvas or focus on doing it in the view, and I know how to do it in a view. But this is kind of behind the scenes, I just want to draw and save in my own image saving class.  I thought for a minute I had it with Graphics, but I couldn't get that to work in Android.

Thank you

Comment: "Is there a native Android way to do this?" -- wrap the bitmap in a `Canvas` using [the supplied `Canvas` constructor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas?hl=en#Canvas(android.graphics.Bitmap)), then draw on the `Canvas`.

Comment: I thought about that, but then I want that bitmap back with the annotations on it.  To compress to jpeg in one case, and to send on to media encoder in another case.

Comment: "but then I want that bitmap back with the annotations on it" -- the `Canvas` operations will update the `Bitmap` that you hand to it. So, when you are done, your `Bitmap` will have the annotations on it.